# Why is Elasticsearch starting manually but not starting as a service on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I installed ELasticsearch 6 and JDK 1.8.0_161 on my ARM Odroid XU4 running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. No errors.

When I attempt to start Elasticsearch as a service, I can't connect to localhost on port 9200 and the service status prints:

```
~ $ > sudo service elasticsearch status
● elasticsearch.service - LSB: Starts elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/elasticsearch; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2018-01-22 10:43:18 UTC; 9min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

Jan 22 10:43:18 lego systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts elasticsearch...
Jan 22 10:43:18 lego systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts elasticsearch.
Jan 22 10:44:07 lego systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts elasticsearch.
```

No logs. No clue where to look. nofile limits are set to 65536 in `/etc/security/limits.conf`. I don't know where else to look for diagnostics.

Although, when I start Elasticsearch manually via `sudo /usr/shared/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch`, it works as expected:

```
~ $ > sudo /usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch
[2018-01-22 10:55:55,944][WARN ][bootstrap                ] jvm uses the client vm, make sure to run `java` with the server vm for best performance by adding `-server` to the command line
[2018-01-22 10:55:56,073][INFO ][node                     ] [Ariel] version[1.7.3], pid[1126], build[NA/NA]
[2018-01-22 10:55:56,074][INFO ][node                     ] [Ariel] initializing ...
[2018-01-22 10:55:56,521][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Ariel] loaded [], sites []
[2018-01-22 10:55:56,638][INFO ][env                      ] [Ariel] using [1] data paths, mounts [[/ (/dev/mmcblk0p2)]], net usable_space 
[54.4gb], net total_space [57.2gb], types [ext4]
[2018-01-22 10:56:01,853][INFO ][node                     ] [Ariel] initialized
[2018-01-22 10:56:01,854][INFO ][node                     ] [Ariel] starting ...
[2018-01-22 10:56:02,080][INFO ][transport                ] [Ariel] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.0.103:9300]}
[2018-01-22 10:56:02,125][INFO ][discovery                ] [Ariel] elasticsearch/FtFOljAORnevIAOAFabptg
[2018-01-22 10:56:05,933][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Ariel] new_master [Ariel][FtFOljAORnevIAOAFabptg][lego]
[inet[/192.168.0.103:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2018-01-22 10:56:05,987][INFO ][http                     ] [Ariel] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/192.168.0.103:9200]}
[2018-01-22 10:56:05,988][INFO ][node                     ] [Ariel] started
[2018-01-22 10:56:06,014][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Ariel] 
recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

What important step am I missing? I followed everything here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html

EDIT: I tried setting `START_DAEMON=true` in `/etc/default/elasticsearch`, which *is* important indeed, but that did not do the trick either. Looking deeper into the values set inside `/etc/default/elasticsearch`, I found the problem in my case. See my final answer for a complete breakdown of the total solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @Suaro states: our problem is related to what is discussed in [this question with nearly identical symptoms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674711/can-not-start-elasticsearch-as-a-service-in-ubuntu-16-04) and [this thread that reiterates the START_DAEMON solution](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cant-start-elasticsearch-with-ubuntu-16-04/48730/9) in the first link. That is a good start, but for me that didn't offer a comprehensive fix. I looked deeper at permissions, heap size, and ownership to find a final solution.

These are the steps for Elasticsearch 6 on Ubuntu 16.04 installed per the [Elasticsearch debian installation instructions](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html) as of Jan 2018:

1. Set `START_DAEMON=true` in `/etc/default/elasticsearch` and restart service.
2. If the system has 2GB of RAM (true in my case), set `ES_HEAP_SIZE=1g`
3. Check the permissions of the elasticsearch directory in `/usr/share/elasticsearch`. Chances are that `root` owns these, which is **not ideal**. *If you don't know already, running any service as root exposes your infrastructure to exploitation by attackers.*
4. The temptation in #3 is to set `ES_USER=root` and `ES_GROUP=root` which will solve your problem. Elasticsearch will start as a service (even though their product documentation alleges that ES won't operate as `root`). **DON'T DO THAT.**
5. Instead, check that the `elasticsearch` user exists locally and that the group of the same name exists too.

   ```
   $ cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
   $ cut -d: -f1 /etc/group
   ```
6. Then, change ownership of all elasticsearch folders and resources to the `elasticsearch` user and group.

   ```
   $ ~ $ > ll /usr/share/elasticsearch/
   total 8.0K
   drwxr-xr-x 2 elasticsearch 4.0K Jan 22 10:02 bin/
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 elasticsearch   18 Dec 24  2015 config -> /etc/elasticsearch/
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 elasticsearch   22 Dec 24  2015 data -> /var/lib/elasticsearch/
   lrwxrwxrwx 1 elasticsearch   22 Dec 24  2015 logs -> /var/log/elasticsearch/
   drwxr-xr-x 2 elasticsearch 4.0K Dec 24  2015 plugins/

   # ^-- Take note that the symlinked directories need to be adjusted too

   $ sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /usr/share/elasticsearch
   $ sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /etc/elasticsearch/
   $ sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/lib/elasticsearch/
   $ sudo chown -R elasticsearch:elasticsearch /var/log/elasticsearch/
   ```
7. Then, set the values `ES_USER=elasticsearch` and `ES_GROUP=elasticsearch` in `/etc/default/elasticsearch` if they aren't set that way already (in case you gave in to temptation per #4).
8. Try it again...

   ```
   ~ $ > sudo service elasticsearch status
   ● elasticsearch.service - LSB: Starts elasticsearch
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/elasticsearch; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
      Active: active (exited) since Mon 2018-01-22 20:51:29 UTC; 2min 25s ago
        Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
     Process: 3133 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Process: 3209 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

   ~ $ > sudo systemctl restart elasticsearch.service

   ~ $ > sudo service elasticsearch status
   ● elasticsearch.service - LSB: Starts elasticsearch
      Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/elasticsearch; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
      Active: active (running) since Mon 2018-01-22 20:54:05 UTC; 2s ago
        Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
     Process: 3306 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Process: 3340 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/elasticsearch start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
              └─3391 /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-armhf/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Delasticsearch -Des.pidfil

   Jan 22 20:54:04 lego systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts elasticsearch...
   Jan 22 20:54:05 lego elasticsearch[3340]:  * Starting Elasticsearch Server
   Jan 22 20:54:05 lego elasticsearch[3340]:    ...done.
   Jan 22 20:54:05 lego systemd[1]: Started LSB: Starts elasticsearch.
   Jan 22 20:51:29 lego systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Starts elasticsearch...
   ```

Et Violà!

```
~ $ > curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/?pretty'
{
  "status" : 200,
  "name" : "Svarog",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "1.7.3",
    "build_hash" : "NA",
    "build_timestamp" : "NA",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "4.10.4"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Comment: that's "Et Voilà!"

Comment: 10000 times thank you, you don't know how much relieved I am now.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly your problem is related to what is discussed in this question.

[Can not start elasticsearch as a service in ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38674711/can-not-start-elasticsearch-as-a-service-in-ubuntu-16-04)

and

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cant-start-elasticsearch-with-ubuntu-16-04/48730/9

If is your case, you must change START_DAEMON to true in /etc/default/elasticsearch and restart service.

Comment: should it be consider as an answer or suggestion.

Comment: My intention is that it was an answer. Do you think I should put it as a suggestion in the comments? Rereading my answer, it could be a suggestion.