# ElasticSearch service starts but can not be reached and does not do any logging

Tags: elasticsearch

ElasticSearch 6.2.2 on Linux Ubuntu 16.04.3 VM in Azure. It had been up and running fine and then after I rebooted the machine a few days ago I could not get the ElasticSearch service to start at all.  Issue was shared and solved here: ([ElasticSearch Fails to Start on Ubuntu 16.04.3 - status=1 Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378279/elasticsearch-fails-to-start-on-ubuntu-16-04-3-status-1-failure/)) by increasing the heap size in the jvm.options file.

Now I have the ElasticSearch service running but I cannot ping it at all.  I have tried to ping it from both inside the VM (as localhost:9200) and from outside, (similar to how I make calls to our other ES boxes, and do so successfully) but I'm told `Could Not Get Any Reponse` (Postman syntax).

The part that is making this impossible to diagnose is nothing is getting written to the ElasticSearch logs!  The last time anything was written to any log at /var/log/elasticsearch was before I rebooted the machine a couple days ago.

I have checked the settings in elasticsearch.yml and all seems to be in-line with the elasticsearch.yml that's on a different box of ours in a different location which runs another ElasticSearch instance of ours without any issue.

**EDIT**: per request - the elasticsearch.yml file from the box that is NOT working correctly is here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=72318548245343478927  For comparison purposes, the elasticsearch.yml file from the box that IS working correctly is here: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=20127693354114612595 Please note that the one that IS working correctly has 3 nodes whereas the one that is not working has only one node, so there will be some *slight* differences between the yml files because of this.

Comment: What does the ES config file look like ?

Comment: Do you mean Elasticsearch.yml?

Comment: Yes, and perhaps try the answer I just wrote

Answer (score 1):

1. Check if `path.logs: /var/log/elasticsearch` is defined in elasticsearch.yml. Add this line if not present.
2. Check whether the user has permission to write into /var/log/elasticsearch. Change the permission of the files. `sudo chmod 777 /var/log/elasticsearch/*` and `sudo chmod 777 /var/log/elasticsearch`
3. Open /etc/init.d/elasticsearch and check whether ES_PATH_CONF is defined as `ES_PATH_CONF="/etc/elasticsearch"`
4. You may try commenting the following lines on log4j2.properties under /etc/elasticsearch.
   `logger.xpack_security_audit_logfile.name = org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.audit.logfile.LoggingAuditTrail
   logger.xpack_security_audit_logfile.level = info
   logger.xpack_security_audit_logfile.appenderRef.audit_rolling.ref = audit_rolling
   logger.xpack_security_audit_logfile.additivity = false`
5. Use `netstat -nultp | grep 9200` and check whether the port is being listened to.

Comment: 1. Yes it is.  2. I ran both these commands.  I ran them from root.  Should I also run as the main user?  3. Yes it is. 4.These lines do not exist in the mentioned file. 5. I received no response when running this command.  Please advise at your most convenient and thanks for your continued help!

Comment: By the way, this box is configured to listen on 9200 via the Azure inbound net rules - so it should definitely be listening on 9200.

Comment: Inbound rules are for the firewall. If netstat did not give a response it means that the ES service has not yet started on 9200. If you have large amount of data it might take a long time to start, even 4 hrs. If sudo service elasticsearch status returns active let it run for a few hours. Keep checking the netstat command to see if it had binded to port 9200

Comment: Can you please share your elasticsearch.yml file in the meantime.

Comment: This ES instance has no data in it.  There are a couple indexes but no data in them yet.  I have attached the yml files in the original post.

Comment: ES definitely is NOT binded to port 9200.  I keep running that command, and nothing.  This surely is the problem.  How to do I fix this?

Comment: @Stpete111 The yml file links have expired. Shows 404.

Comment: sorry about that, new links posted.

Comment: Still no logs being written for the last 2 days.  This is so very odd.

Comment: This is an extremely weird problem. Can you put elasticsearch.yml to its default settings and try starting the service.

Comment: The issue is resolved.  Arnav I can't thank you enough for your help and attention.

Comment: Arnav, can we continue a discussion about ElasticSearch in a chat?  I have a question for you.

Comment: Hi @Stpete111, sorry for the late reply. We can continue the discussion on chat. Let me know when you are available. Great to hear this is problem is finally solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180540/discussion-between-stpete111-and-arnavray).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was with the line in the ElasticSearch.yml file which showed as

```
"10.5.11.6""
```

That extra quotation mark at the end is what was causing the entire problem.

For anyone that this can benefit, the ElasticSearch.yml file is **extremely** sensitive when it comes to space, punctuation and case: even an extra space somewhere can cause the entire service to crash.  Be very diligent with your edits to elasticsearch.yml.

Answer (score 0):

There are ways to debug:

```
1. Check if you have ES service running on that particular host via `ps -ef | grep elastic`
2. Look on which port es is listening (or not) ? via netstat 
3. it might be a case that your es is running and but is binding not to localhost but to the instance IP . You should be getting the hint on the elasticsearch.yaml 
4. Make sure your /usr/share/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yaml is the file that is being picked up and not the default at /etc/elasticsearch.yaml
5. Configure logging in elasticsearch.yaml to the location
```

Hope this helps?

Comment: Thanks Nishant - I'm still very new to this so I'll need some more detailed guidance:  1. That command give me a LOT of information, what am I looking for in there?  2.  Running netstat -a I see nothing about ElasticSearch in any of the LISTENING rows.  Problem there I guess?  3. How can I determine this for sure?  I've configured the es.yml file to be consistent with our other instance on the other box which is working correctly.  4. Ok, I'm confused about this - again, on our other box that's working fine, it's using the etc/elasticsearch.yml is the one being used.  Are you sure about this?

Comment: 5. let me take a look at that one and see if there is an issue with that.